# Spark+Hive integration testing with Docker

Tags: docker, apache-spark, hadoop, hive

I have Spark+Hive job that is working fine.

I'm trying to configure the environment for local development and integration testing:

1. Docker [images](https://github.com/big-data-europe/docker-hive) to bootstrap Hive Server, metastore, etc
2. Docker [image](https://github.com/gettyimages/docker-spark/blob/master/Dockerfile) with Spark environment/local cluster

Now I have docker-compose for #1 that runs the entire environment (including Hive metastore) and I can connect to this metastore with beeline tool.

I can run my spark with docker run using the image from #2 and it is running.

The problem I have is related to Hive configuration. Whenever the job is trying to read the table within SparkContext it fails with:

```
[Error] [JvmBridge] java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: HIVE_STATS_JDBC_TIMEOUT
```

Hadoop: 2.7.3
Spark: 2.4.5
hive-metastore jar: 2.1.1

Spark submit params (/var/lib is the correct path):

```
--conf spark.sql.hive.metastore.version=2.1.1 --conf spark.sql.hive.metastore.jars=/var/lib/*
```

hive-site.xml (added to Hive and Spark config folders)

```
<configuration>
    <property><name>hive.metastore.warehouse.dir</name><value>hdfs://localhost:50075</value></property>
    <property><name>hive.metastore.uris</name><value>thrift://localhost:9083</value></property>
    <property><name>spark.sql.uris</name><value>thrift://localhost:9083</value></property>
    <property><name>hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode</name><value>nonstrict</value></property>
    <property><name>hive.exec.dynamic.partition</name><value>true</value></property>
</configuration>
```

How to demystify this error?

Comment: If Spark is in a sepearate container, then `localhost` wont work when referring to Hive, but "No such field" would indicate an error in the versioning of the jars you're adding

Comment: there is no issue with the hostname. I provided `localhost` as an example. is there any chance to get a proper list of lib versions?

Comment: I've never seen these configs to override the metastore version or jars. Out of the box, Spark-Hive integration should work assuming the metastore uris are correct... Howver, I've personally not [tried changing any versions](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.5/sql-migration-guide-hive-compatibility.html) of Hive